# Python - Formatting Data into Excel Spreadsheet Using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want two columns of data the team name and the line. However all my input is just placed into cell B1. (Note that was with the commented out code at the bottom of my snippet). I think I need to iterate through my lists with for loops to get all the teams down the A column, and lines down the B column, but just can't wrap my head around it while doing it with pandas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

```
team = []
line = []
# Each row in table find all rows with class name team
for tr in table.find_all("tr", class_="team"):
    # Place all text with identifier 'name' in list named team
    for td in tr.find_all("td", ["name"]):
        team.append(td.text.strip())


for tr in table.find_all("tr", class_="team"):

    for td in tr.find_all("td", ["currentline"]):
        line.append(td.text.strip())
 # Amount of data in lists  
 x = len(team)

# Team name is list team, Line in list line. Create relationship between both data sets
# Creating Excel Document and Placing Team Name in column A, Placing Line in Column B

#Need to add data into Excel somehow
for i in range(0,1):

    for j to line:




""" data = {'Team':[team], 'line' : [line]}

table = pd.DataFrame(data)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Scrape.xlsx')
table.to_excel(writer, 'Scrape 1')

writer.save()"""
```

Comment: Your commented out code produces what you wish in my testing.

Comment: It places all my results into cell B1 I want the teams in one column and the lines in another column. Does that make sense? @bernie

Comment: It makes sense I'm just saying that in my testing the output is as you wish.

Comment: Hmm thats really weird any idea why that would be, what year excel do you have? @bernie

Comment: I'm on 2013 now. No idea what is going wrong in your case...

Comment: Odd, well hopefully someone can shed some light on this... My A1 Cell is a 0 and all of the data I want in the columns is in B1. Thanks anyways! @bernie

Comment: Oh I think I see what's going on...

Comment: Can you try your code below beginning with this: `data = {'Team': team, 'line': line}`? They are already lists and putting brackets around them makes them lists of lists.

Comment: I'll check shortly I'm at work haha, that sounds like it should work though! I'll keep you posted! @bernie

Comment: Alright. Good luck.

Comment: YEA BABY! Thanks @bernie much appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should not do this because you're making lists of lists:

```
data = {'Team':[team], 'line' : [line]}
# ...
```

Instead do:

```
data = {'Team': team, 'line': line}
# ...
```